How to run an .exe file in the GUI of a python program
I want to make a python program with GUI that contains a gui like desktop (a simple environment) with a few buttons on it, let's say it has a button to open visual studio code, and when I click that I want visual studio code to open, BUT inside the environment that I made using python, so it's width and height must be less than the environment and it must be completely inside of it, the background behind the vs code must be of the gui of my python program, is this possible to achieve in python?
or any other way to achieve this in any other language?
I tried to find it on Internet but found nothing!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

tkinter for GUI(button) , then run .bat file

May I get a documentation/resource link for that, please? and .bat file with what code to run the .exe file?
Thanks for the response!
